# How to use bash tail command inside a custom pipe command script?

Tags: bash

I want to use tail in my custom pipe command.

For example, I want to execute this command:

```
>ls -1 | tail -n 1 | awk '{print "last file is "$1}'
>last file is test.txt
```

And I want to make it short by making my own custom script. It looks like this:

```
>ls -1 | myscript
>last file is test.txt
```

I know myscript can get input from "ls -1" by this code:

```
while read line; do
    echo last file is $line
done
```

But I don't know how to use "tail -n 1" in the custom pipe command code above.

Is there a way to use a pipe command in another pipe command script?

Or do I have to implement the code which does the same process as "tail -n 1" myself?

I hope bash has some solution for this.

Comment: You can replace both the `tail` and `awk` commands with `sed -n '$ s/^/last file is /p'` -- the `-n` means "don't print lines unless specifically told to", the `$` means "on the last line..." and the rest means replace `^` (the beginning of the line) with "last file is ", and print the result.

Comment: If all what you want is to print the (lexicographically) last file in the current directory, this can be done in plain `bash` without resorting to external commands:  `files=(*); echo "last file is ${files[-1]}"`

Comment: Side note: [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls(1)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting just this in `myscript`

```
tail -n 1 | awk '{print "last file is "$1}'
```

This works as the first command (tail) consumes the stdin of your script. In general, scripts work as though you typed their contest as-is to the terminal.

Comment: thank you for the answer and the explanation how it works. The code works perfectly as if by magic!

Comment: Try making it fail. Adjust the tail command to take a file as the file argument. Then make it work again, i.e. can you figure out what you need to put here ./myscript ??????? to replicate ls -1 | ./myscript.

Comment: thank you for the quiz! I searched a lot. ./myscript <(ls -1) is the answer? I changed myscript to, echo last file is $(tail -n 1 $1)

Comment: @user_, you're almost there. Your script would be ```tail -n 1 "${@:--}" | awk '{print "last file is "$1}'```. Then it can EITHER: stdin (piped in) OR parameter on cli (<(ls -1).

Comment: @vgersh99 thank you for the answer! but in my mac terminal, your code outputs an error for pipe. the error message is,  `tail: -: No such file or directory`. I modified it to, `tail -n 1 ${1-} | awk '{print "last file is "$1}'` and it works for pipe too. What does `"${@:--}"` mean?